# Weird bug , PHP code get prints in browser screen instead execution 

Tags: php

I am making some code , But it is so strange that code just get prints on screen , I am not able to find any reason of it.

Please help me out of this, rest of the code is working fine.

Thanks

Comment: Post the offending code?

Comment: Is it a general problem or does it happens only to one script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very annoying problem. There is an error for sure. Check your web server logs but I doubt the it will be helpful. I solved that problem by using die(); in the script and printing some variables on screen using var_dump and/or print_r. Try to break the script in peaces to isolate and find the problem.

Comment: yes buddy indeed very annoying . i solved and answered plz check . Thanks :) . But some people think it is not programming related (Shocking :O )

Answer (score 3):

The server is not correctly configured to run php ;)

Or your file has no .php file extension.

Comment: But all the other code working fine and yes it is PHP extension

Comment: If you don't provide details, this is just a guessing game

Comment: mate very hard to tell what detail will be haelpfull, i chekced all .htaccess , extension , tags all is okay and rest of the files on same server are working fine

Comment: Well, like... the code? If it's too long, reduce it to the smallest possible version which reproduces the error.

Comment: i answered myself plz check , and Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Missing `<?php` would be the obvious possibility to check first

Comment: And any files that you include() also have the <?php

Answer (score 0):

Since you provide no detail at all i can just guess:

Is the file extension correct?
Is there a .htaccess or server configuration that makes apache not interpret the file as php?